# Show HTML in component

Tags: vue.js

I use v-html in component. It does not work. Maybe I am making mistake, I don't know what is a mistake.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <my-component></my-component>
        <script type="text/x-template" id="my-component">
            <div>
                <p v-html="showModalUpdate"></p>
                <p>This is the content of component</p>
                <p>Hello Vue!</p>               
            </div>            
        </script>
    </div>
        <script>
            Vue.component('my-component',{
                    template:'#my-component'
            });
            var app=new Vue({
                el:"#app",
                data: {
                    showModalUpdate: '<h1>Hello There</h1>',                
},
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How to make it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Move your `data` declaration to `my-component` and make it a function.

---

Two issues here:

1. You are trying to refer to `data` from the `app` component from `my-component`. This does not work, either use the inner component's own `data` or pass it down from the parent using `props`
2. `data` must be a function, not a plain object.

The console logs should tell you exactly that:

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "showModalUpdate" is not defined 
on the instance but referenced during render. 
Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, 
or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

To fix this, move your `data` to `my-component` like this:

```
Vue.component("my-component", {
  template: "#my-component",
  data: {
    showModalUpdate: "<h1>Hello There</h1>"
  }        
});
```

Now the second issue shows in the console:

```
The "data" option should be a function that 
returns a per-instance value in component definitions.
```

To fix it, make `data` into a function:

```
Vue.component("my-component", {
  template: "#my-component",
  data: function () {
    return {
      showModalUpdate: "<h1>Hello There</h1>"
    }
  }        
});
```

You can find more in the docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which helped me understand v-html

Answer (score -1):

According to wwerner's solution, the demo html likes this:

```
< html>
< head>
    < meta charset="utf-8">
        < script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js">
            < /script>
                < /head>
                    < body>
                        < div id="app">
                            < my - component ref="test">
                                < /my-component>
                                    < button type="button" @click="clicktest"> Yes < /button>
                                            < script type="text/x-template" id="my-component">
                                                < div>
                                                    < p v - html="showModalUpdate">
                                                        < /p>
                                                            < p> This is the content of component < /p>
                                                                    < p> Hello Vue! < /p>
                                                                            < /div>
                                                                                < /script>
                                                                                    < /div>
                                                                                        < script>
                                                                                            Vue.component('my-component', {
                                                                                            template: '#my-component',
                                                                                            data: function() {
                                                                                            return {
                                                                                            showModalUpdate: "<h1>Hello There</h1>"
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            },

                                                                                            created: function() {
                                                                                            console.log(111);
                                                                                            this.showModalUpdate = '<h1>Are You There</h1>'
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            methods: {
                                                                                            getetail() {
                                                                                            this.showModalUpdate = '<h1>Hello There2</h1>';
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            }

                                                                                            });
                                                                                            var app = new Vue({
                                                                                            el: "#app",
                                                                                            // data: {
                                                                                            // showModalUpdate: '<h1>Hello There</h1>',
                                                                                            // },
                                                                                            created: function() {
                                                                                            console.log(this.showModalUpdate);
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            methods: {
                                                                                            clicktest: function() {
                                                                                            //console.log(this.$refs.test);
                                                                                            this.$refs.test.getetail();
                                                                                            ///console.log(this.$refs.test);
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                            }); < /script>
                                                                                                < /body>
                                                                                                    < /html>
```